Почему программа на C++ в VS Code при ошибках начинает ломать компьютер?
Возможно, моя проблема слишком специфическая, чтобы её можно было воспроизвести на другом компьютере, но всё же...
Я заметил, что по какой-то причине практически любое неопределённое поведение в моих программ на C++ заканчивается очень странными "симптомами":

потеря возможности остановить программу в IDE (кнопка просто не реагирует)
странные баги операционной системы (например, отключение проводника вместе с рабочим столом)
прекращение работы кнопок "перезагрузка", "завершение работы" и т. д.
поломка встроенных приложений Windows (опционально)

Как-то у меня перестал работать журнал буфера обмена (надо сказать, он до сих не открывается), и сейчас этот замечательный "комплекс" выполняется после каждого неудачного запуска. Мне приходится перезагружать компьютер кнопкой питания.
В данном случае неопределённое поведение возникает в результате отсутствия файла IntegratorUI.jar:
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "Integrator.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int n,char*args[]){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(strcmp(args[i],"-ui")==0){
            checkAccess();
            JavaVM*jvm;
            JNIEnv*env;
            JavaVMOption opt[1];
            opt->optionString=const_cast<char*>("-cp ./IntegratorUI.jar");
            JavaVMInitArgs jargs;
            jargs.nOptions=1;
            jargs.options=opt; 
            JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void**)&env,&jargs);
        }
    }
}

void checkAccess(){}

Сдаётся мне, даже неопределённое поведение не должно портить мне компьютер.
Кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить? Может, есть какие-то настройки в VS Code, позволяющие запустить программу так, чтобы в случае чего она просто остановилась?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
